# How to randomly crop a batch of images

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have a batch of 5 images, I want to randomly crop them for w_, h_ size

Example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
images=tf.reshape(tf.range(100*100*3*5), [100, 100, 3, 5])    
batch_crop = tf.random_crop(images, size=(20, 20))
with tf.Session() as sess:
     batch = sess.run([batch_crop])
```

I get error:
**ValueError: Shape must be rank 4 but is rank 3 for 'concat' (op: 'ConcatV2') with input shapes:**

Comment: What version of tensorflow are you running? Copy-pasting that code in `1.12.0` gave me the error of `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`. Also, in your version, what does `tf.random` do? Can you link the documentation? I don't understand how that achieves a crop?

Comment: @IanQuah, sorry it is `tf.random_crop` and I am using  1.9.0 version

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your example. I get an error of `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 4 and 2 for 'random_crop/GreaterEqual' (op: 'GreaterEqual') with input shapes: [4], [2]` on line `batch_crop = tf.random_crop(images, size=(20, 20))`. Is the error you're getting from the example you've pasted? That's what I'm going off of to try and address this

Comment: Wait, what are you trying to do? So given 5 images of shape `(100, 100, 3)` you want to crop out `(20,20)` from them? So the resulting shape will be `(20, 20, 3, 5)`?

Comment: @IanQuah, yes Exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note the extra `(3, 5)` at the end of size. This effectively tells tensorflow that it should not be cropped along the third and fourth axis

```
import tensorflow as tf
images=tf.reshape(tf.range(100*100*3*5), [100, 100, 3, 5])    
batch_crop = tf.random_crop(images, size=(20, 20, 3, 5))
with tf.Session() as sess:
     batch = sess.run([batch_crop])
```

Should do the job. From the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/random_crop), `random_crop`  returns

> A cropped tensor of the same rank as value and shape size.

The part that you'll want to pay extra attention to is probably:

> If a dimension should not be cropped, pass the full size of that dimension. For example, RGB images can be cropped with size = [crop_height, crop_width, 3].

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The problem with random_crop is that it crops all images in the batch in the exact same position. Still have not found a method to do it independently for each image